# set cookie from http://sitedomain to https://sitedomain and back again

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to save a cookie when going from http: // sitedomain to https : // sitedomain.  The https side contains all the login stuff and account related stuff, when I go back to http side the cookie that was originally in the http side of thing made it to the https side of things but expired there.  And when I returned to the http side of things the cookie was back to a default value and didn't remember the value b/c it has expired when it went to the https side even though I renewed it on the https side.  How can I keep the cookie key and value throughout the transition from http to https?  Should I immediately call an ajax call to the http side when in the https side to maintain the http: // sitedomain for that cookie key and value or can I use just the an https cookie.  I've read that https cookies cannot ever work consistently between all browsers on the https side and the same domain for http side.

On the http side I have php, c# mvc4 .net 4.5, and javascript get cookie and set cookie methods.  On the https side I'm using only asp.net web forms get cookie and set cookie methods.  Trying to figure out the best technique to use.  What would the web forms get and set cookie method look like for a key like: "MyKey", value: "from http" when just transitioned from an http to https site.  And key: "MyKey" value: "from https" when just transitioning from an https to http site?  Otherwise its contains the value of the last page visited which already works.